# Rspec "edit" action routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Consistently having problems correctly testing for routes to the "edit" action. I suspect it's because the 'edit' action has associated edit_ids? I.e., you're never going to see /edit, but always /edit/asdfsafsadfds(ID string).

Not sure what the convention is in this case. Here is the RSpec I have:

```
describe "create - with valid data" do
    it "redirects to edit action" do
        post :create, request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:request)
        response.should redirect_to :controller => :requests, :action => :edit
    end
...
end
```

Note that I have also tried redirect_to 'edit', redirect_to :edit, render_template 'edit', render_template :edit, and all of them fail. For reference:

Controller code:

```
def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    if @request.save
    ...
    redirect_to edit_request_path(@request.edit_id)
    ...
    end
end
```

Routes code:

```
get 'edit/:edit_id', to: 'requests#edit', as: 'edit_request'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be redirecting to the "show" page?

Comment: No, in this case, I'm redirecting directly to an edit page where they can change the information they just input.

Comment: @james Where's the error?

Comment: You can use `redirect_to assigns[:instance_variable]` I believe

Comment: correction: `redirect_to edit_request_url(assigns[:request])`

Comment: here's what's happening. edit_request_url(assigns[:request]) takes me to test.host/edit/1, which normally would be right. In this case, the model is creating an edit id (there’s a before_create :create_edit_id) that the controller users to redirect edits. I.e., the edit is actually going to test.host/edit/WPIUREKSDFKJK. Any thoughts on how to specify this in the test? "Assigns[:request.edit_id]" returns a no method error on edit_id, even after in the FactoryGirl I’m explicitly creating an edit_id for the request (override whatever the model is creating, OK since here i'm testing redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH Per my last comment @veritas1, you got me 90% there. What I was trying to do was right, I just wrote it wrong. It's supposed to be

```
redirect_to edit_request_url(assigns[:request].edit_id)
```

NOT assigns[:request.edit_id]